# Local Langlands conjecture for GL(2)

Tags: automorphic-forms, galois-representations, langlands-conjectures

Let $F_v$ be a local field. Let $\sigma_v$ be a two-dimensional representation of $Gal(\overline{F}_v:F_v) \rtimes W_{F_v}$. Now, there exists an infinite-dimensional representation $\pi_v$ of $GL_2(F_v)$, whose local $L$-functions and root number coincides with that of $\sigma_v$ .

> How and to what extent can we read off the $\pi_v$ from $\sigma_v$?

When is $\pi_v$ a supercuspidal rep, an unramified, or ramified principal series rep, a Steinberg representation, a discrete series representation? What properties of $\sigma_v$ are decisive?

Comment: Marc, I think you don't have the global Langlands formalism right.
Automorphic forms for $Gl_2(\mathbb A_F)$ do not correspond to two-dimensional Galois representation as you say, but to representation of a much larger group, conjectural, called the Langlands group $L_F$. This group is not profinite in particular, nor are his local counterparts, and complex representations of those will in general **not** have **finite image**. 


Comment: I know. I am not saying that automorphic reps can be mapped to Galois reps, but only that Galois reps inject into automorphic forms.

Comment: I tried to make this clearer now. Are there still objections?

Comment: Joël: I assume you are talking about Maass forms?

Comment: Yes. What is the Weil-Deligne group of a global field ?

Comment: The Yes of my preceding comment answered the question "Are there still objections?". No, I am not talking only about Maass forms. 
I believe that the four comments I have written below my answer
to that question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127157/status-of-global-langlands-conjecture-for-gl-2-over-mathbbq/127166#127166
may be useful to clarify the relevant point.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of that. The question was local in spirit, so I was able to rephrase the question. Is it safe now?

Comment: Dear Marc, Your description of $\sigma_v$ is wrong (at least, if you intended to write the usual thing that appears on the "Galois side" of local Langlands).  Namely, what $\sigma_v$ should be is a *Frobenius semisimple Weil--Deligne representation*, which is a representation of   the Weil group $W_{F_v}$ which has open kernel when restricted to inertia, together with a nilpotent operator that satisfies a certain commutation relation.  If $\sigma_v$ is unramified (including $N = 0$), we get unram. principal series.  If $\sigma_v$ is ramified but reducible, and $N \neq 0$, we get ... 

Comment: ... ramified p.s.  If $N \neq 0$, and $\sigma_v$ is trivial on the inertia in $W_{F_v}$, we get an unramified twist of Steinberg.   If $N \neq 0,$ and $\sigma_v$ is non-trivial on inertia in $W_{F_v}$, we get a ramified twist of Steinberg.  If $\sigma_v$ is irred. on $W_{F_v}$ (in which case $N$ necessarily $= 0$), we get a supercuspidal.  Combining these, one finds that discrete series arises precisely when $\sigma_v$ is indecomposable.  Regards, Matthew

Comment: Dear Matthew, I am totally satisfied with your explanation. Would you like to copy and paste it as an answer? Thank you=)